# Rails form to database setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, forms, model, sqlite

I'm fairly new to Rails, and I have a few beginner's questions. I want to create a beta signup page for my web app, something like this http://www.realestapp.com/ . How do I go about initializing such a rails project - what gems should I install and what generate commands should I use? I know I need a User model, with a string attribute to save an email address. I want to save the user email address from the form into a sqlite3 database.

Thanks!

Comment: This is a very broad question. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried generating the model and controller separately, and coding but for some reason I keep getting this error "undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class"... I think I would be better off starting fresh.

Comment: Without seeing the code and full stack trace, i can't really give any advice...

Comment: I want to start a new project, how would you set up a new rails project if you were doing this?

Comment: `rails new <projectname>` `cd <projectname>` `rails g model user` Update migration to add email field `rails g controller email` Add actions to the controller to render the form and handle submission of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a big fan of the nifty gem (https://github.com/ryanb/nifty-generators).  It greatly reduces headaches.  Add it to your gemfile and run `bundle install`.  Then you can just:

```
rails generate nifty:scaffold User email:string
```

Comment: I'll certainly take a look at it